# OdbcConnection open() doesn't work

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

```
protected OdbcConnection conectarBD()
{
    String StringDeConexion = "Data Source=PABLOZN\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Proyecto2;Integrated Security=True";

    try
    {
        OdbcConnection conexion = new OdbcConnection(StringDeConexion);
        conexion.Open();
        return conexion;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Label3.Text = ex.StackTrace.ToString();
        return null;
    }
}
```

**The problem is that when I browse my website, the Label shows this exception on the line number 18**:

> en System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection.HandleError(OdbcHandle hrHandle,
>   RetCode retcode) en
>   System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnectionHandle..ctor(OdbcConnection connection,
>   OdbcConnectionString constr, OdbcEnvironmentHandle environmentHandle)
>   en System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnectionOpen..ctor(OdbcConnection
>   outerConnection, OdbcConnectionString connectionOptions) en
>   System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions
>   options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo,
>   DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject) en
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions
>   options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo,
>   DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection,
>   DbConnectionOptions userOptions) en
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions) en
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal&
>   connection) en
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) en
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) en
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.OpenConnection(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory) en
>   System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection.Open() en index.conectarBD() en
>   c:..\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2012\WebSites\Proyecto\index.aspx.cs:línea 18

Comment: Why are you using ODBC to connect to a SQL server, why are you using the Native SqlClient?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

Verify that the user has access to the database . How do you use trusted connection , verify that the current user has access to the database . If your application is web , make sure NETWORKSERVICE can connect to the database.

You also can try to configure the connection string via DSN in windows ODBC manager.

Comment: I think that the user has access to the database. I got the connection string from Visual Studio and I have no idea how to make sure networkservice can connect to the data base or how to configure the connection string via DSN. I can't work on it and I need to have it done soon. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: Try to copy all the error content and post here .

You can also enable mixed authentication mode sql server . To do this , follow the steps shown on the link below . After accomplishing the configuration , set a password for the user SA

Enter in your connectionstring the user and password . Use the sa user to test .

Any problems post a comment

Comment: [How to enable mixed authentication in sql server](http://www.lansweeper.com/kb/23/SQLserver-enable-mixed-authentication.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can either change OdbcConnection to SqlConnection or if for some reason, you must use ODBC the connection string will look like this:

@"DRIVER=SQL Server Native Client 11.0;SERVER=PABLOZN\SQLEXPRESS;DATABASE=Proyecto2;Trusted_Connection=Yes;"